# PayPal Integration in Android

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I just want to know can we integrate PayPal sdk in android with out Braintree support.

Because i just want to do payment from Android app using paypal only.

Comment: This is PayPal SDK, deprecated But you can use it.  https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Comment: you can still use it , but don't use it as it is deprecated for a long time now .

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support.

I would recommend writing in to our Sales team to see if processing PayPal only through Braintree is an option for you. You can reach our Sales team by going to braintreepayments.com and clicking on the "Contact Sales" button at the top right.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? Even official SDK isn't working now.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be followed by each and everyone moving forward. 
No further delays would be acceptable.
Let’s we help you
to know how can you do this.
let me know the each of the status.
Please check and confirm possible or not.
 If possible then please continue
 If you have any questions for the same then discuss with me.
 These change need to be fix asap.
Hope you are well
I see it well